# Sampling from the normal-gamma distribution in R

Tags: r, distributions, bayesian, normal-distribution, gamma-distribution

Does anyone know of a way to sample from the normal-gamma bivariate distribution or the normal-inverse-gamma bivariate distribution in R?

I could create the distribution myself as a function, but then I would not know what to do to sample from it.

Comment: The wikipedia page [gives an algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal-gamma_distribution#Generating_normal-gamma_random_variates)

Answer (score 5):

Sampling from normal-gamma distribution is easy, and in fact the algorithm is described on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal-gamma_distribution):

> Generation of random variates is straightforward:
>
> - Sample $\tau$ from a gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$
> - Sample $x$ from a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $1/(\lambda \tau)$

What leads to the following function:

```r
rnormgamma <- function(n, mu, lambda, alpha, beta) {
  if (length(n) > 1) 
    n <- length(n)
  tau <- rgamma(n, alpha, beta)
  x <- rnorm(n, mu, sqrt(1/(lambda*tau)))
  data.frame(tau = tau, x = x)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, for `x<-rnorm(n, mu, sqrt(1/(lambda*tau)))`, why is it `sqrt()`? Here $x\sim N(\mu, 1/(\lambda T))$, right?

Comment: Because `rnorm` is parametrized by standard deviation, not variance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `rigamma()` function from the pscl package on CRAN. You can also take a look at the ghyp package.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I'm looking for a way to contain vector samples from a bi-variate normal-gamma/normal-inverse-gamma distribution in R. I looked at those packages and they are focused mainly on the regular inverse gamma or the normal inverse gaussian.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is very late, but did you can approximate samples from the normal inverse gamma bivariate distribution using a Gibbs Sampler where the two alternating sampling distributions would be the normal distribution and the inverse gamma distribution. Did you look into that?

Comment: the gibbs sampler does the following to approximate f(x,y): step1. intitalize x, x=x1 (arbitrary) , step2. simulate y1=f(y|x=x1), step3. simulate x2=f(x|y=y2), step4. simulate y2=f(y|x=x2),etc...., this is a markov chain, which after a "burn-in" period will become stationary and be an approximation of f(x,y).

Comment: The bivariate normal-inverse-gamma, has special relevance in bayesian statistics as it  is the posterior distribution for f(mu,sigma | sample), the parameters of the normal distribution,  assuming you choose conjugate priors for sigma  (the inverse gamma ) and mu (the normal distribution) for mu. This means that you can approximate  f(mu,sigma| sample), by simulating from f(mu | sigma, sample)~Inverse-Gamma and f(sigma | mu, sample)~Normal.

Comment: I wrote an example of how you can do it: http://rpubs.com/emdiazsal/6194

Comment: its not actually a gibbs sampler. I realize the gibbs sampler would be overkill in this situation. Let me know if it helps!